# Why no Directory.Copy in C#

Tags: c#, .net, directory

I am making a program in C# with a lot of IO operations.
Some of that operations are copying directories.

I was really stunned when I figured out that you don't have something like Directory.copy(SourceDir, DestinationDir) in C#.

I googled a little bit around and at msdn they give a code sample to copy directories.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx).
But when you search a little bit further, there is a Directory.Copy method in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO namespace. 
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127957.aspx)

I could refere to this namespace and use this method, but there must be a reason why Microsoft does not support this in C# and why they aren't mentioning it on msdn.

Hope somebody can tell me the reason.

I can write extensionmethod to solve this problem & I can solve it pretty easy, but my question is Why? Why is there no such method in C#, I just want to know :-)

Comment: The VB team added some Utils for things that you could have easily developed yourself using the available classes.

Comment: **Why** would be impossible for anyone but the developers of the framework to answer. We can only speculate, more or less educatedly. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's easy enough to do a `foreach` on a `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`, while also giving you an opportunity to filter the list of files being copied, or do some other operation besides copying.

If it really bothers you, write an extension method for the `DirectoryInfo` class, or a `FileInfo[]` collection.

Comment: So why is it available in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO namespace for VB.NET and it is not available in a namespace for C#?

Comment: @Bram: Xml Literals are also available in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace, as well as a few other things.  The C# team prefers brevity; if a feature doesn't provide significant value-added, they don't include it.

Comment: @Bram Possibly for legacy reasons. VB.NET is, after all, full of legacy syntax and constructs to make it easier for VB6 developers to migrate to .NET.

Comment: To bad it is closed, thanks anyway Mr. R. Harvey =)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that VB is oriented more on beginners and things like `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` were intended to attract them to .NET world.